# How come my begin variable is not chaning in the function?

Tags: python

begin = 0
def add():
print(begin)

def subtract():
begin += 1

subtract()
add()

How come the begin variable isnt being changed in my subtract function so that the add function will print "1"?

Comment: Is this previous answer about [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/21146235) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Meh this code may not even work. Because normally they use a local variable in the function when changing its variable. If you want to use a global variable just add global begin  in you function. for example:

```
def subtract():
    global begin 
    begin += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`begin` inside `subtract()` function is a local variable. Any assignment to a local variable cannot affect global variable of same name. Function `add` has access to global variable `begin` only.

To make changes in `subtract` effect global variable, you have to explicitly declare it as a global variable inside `subtract` function as follows:

```py
begin = 0 
def add(): 
  print(begin)

def subtract(): 
  global begin
  begin += 1

subtract() 
add()
# prints 1
```